# How find_library does handle so version numbers?

Tags: cmake

How does CMake's `find_library` handle so version numbers like in "libFOO.so.3.2"? Some libraries have symbolic links from libFOO.so to the right version, some do not.

Does CMake find a library without the symbolic link when I just use `find_library(NAMES FOO)`?
What should I do to help CMake figuring out the right library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a linux distribution, the system package manager will generally provide runtime packages and development packages.  If you have installed the development package for a library (e.g. libFOO-dev), it will generally include the following three files in your /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib

```
libFOO.so.3.2.0 (the versioned binary)
libFOO.so.3 (soname = symlink to versioned binary)
libFOO.so (namelink = symlink to soname)
```

The namelink has no version details in the file name.  This will be used to find the library by linker command line option, e.g. -lFOO

You should use the namelink (e.g. FOO) in the find_library cmake command.

The linker will embed the soname file into your binary.

If you have multiple versions of the library installed, be sure to symlink the namelink file to the soname file that you want to use.  This is really only an issue if you have multiple major versions of the same library installed.  Within a major version, APIs should be backwards compatible.

Comment: As a consequence, CMake might find an so library only if the devel packaged are also installed, right? I wasn't aware of that. Devel packages often have tons of additional dependencies.

Comment: The soname (shared object name) is what is embedded in linked binaries, so it should be installed without needing an associated development package, i.e. it is a runtime requirement. The development package would add the namelink (since this is used only at link time, not runtime) and headers.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @marksisson's answer:

In case you download an SDK as a zip archive with such symlinked `.so` files it may happen that the symlinks are broken. Instead of real symlinks you have small text files containing the names of the linked files. As a consequence the linker complains about an unrecognizable file format.

To fix that, just recreate the symlinks after unpacking the zip file.